# Simplifying API of classes extending each other by CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, api-design, crtp, template-templates

I want to write class that extends multiple classes by ([CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)).

I can only get `Extension<Base<Extension>> my_object;` to work.

The api that I want is: `Extension<Base> my_object;`

How to make this api work?

Thanks.

Test (code is also at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwnlSCCxTEwC2G7BwAMAQQuWCmIwAdmd9VruPnmDZoIBPB5gsxpgAdGGmqkpMgoKq2AAediyCOiymNlExqjzRmLSqIKoOIgBGDHjIcYmBKahpWjmCed4JSbX1ZrLY6gDsfFbFZRUgNqpjqnpMBBWqAG6oeOiqJZiYDhAAlL08EwToICiiBK6a3upcvLn53FwaOxw9ACI2D8%2By/dZWAPRf7k5TmBOf083j8ASCRlC4S6kWYWVaNVS6W%2BX0ysUamAA%2BiwRAwGAUiqVypUEckkVpLNjcQwWtUyXV0jCHh8foNiSMUeNdlMZvNFstVustszXjYfqL3i8rMCASc0aoAArKYAKZGWeWk9rXPo2NnDUbjTWpWibAlOEQqliYiCTabITHIaIEbxKi0KABUpggBAQeEEG2FOqeBrGfKWKzWppFVi5XPNlsxAFpTBGhXcQ7G9PtDiJjt4zjcjXVaBwAKyaNIXdMx8aigbEPCzAEcyxc12W91FZUKTHV6zByVWGwylyg%2Bz/Oyg/yBYJhEIReXt1VdDJw2JFlhcba6on6mtjDdcU2FeM9m0EHn2x16F3d%2BqaQ%2BmT1db2%2B/2BvjB/dzBbhwVRnVvzjO8kxTf8Nj7WNxizA40FzE4CwuR9y0rW5B1bWsv0sBwGybOwWzbO9aTaVI0OwTtTytPsJQ%2BGwFGOIwmAUACPi5H5VAAFTfVQAHcSAAa0Eedvw3EsGiuYjEWLRlsBKSDxhKEJU02eSxnYri/VUdBUEwQQWDAKRjj44h%2BOEjCDzpdo0M0DExO6Th0K5ZAlPA1TVAMAgxBYVRzGop4pA2RhpFLKRSBYaRzFC1BpFOXh%2BAmURxEBORaFCggIoCwL%2BJAUtzCCqQABZQvCqRItIaKpFCwQQDy9LSoC0g4FgJA0EcPAGEwMgKAgVqHHazqQGAHpZFIAAzdq7GIaqIBKDLSBKBQmGIXxpFS0hWshFgCAAeRYBgVvq0gsEYtgOrm/ADGQaZZl0ubMHiTBkFzSQpDW%2BjMAYOb9DwIwMsC5g2BQfh%2BEYPASmqyBAtQBxpjqaqpETbbRqdKrEokOh/uC4q5oq%2BIAA4ADZEwJgrVGAZBKh6EJZFUCBcEIEhzlkehVE0VA2o64gmdoLZYr4Xg0r%2BrKcryz7Cuxw6KqqmrSDqyKA3yrgJbKqXZaF0gbqm1IQAKoA%3D)):

```
#include <iostream>

template <template<typename...> class Extension>
class Base1 : public Extension<Base1<Extension>> {
public:
    static void beep() { std::cout << "Base1 "; }
};

template <class Plugin>
class Extension1 {
public:
    Extension1() : plugin_(static_cast<Plugin*>(this)) {}
    void beep() {
        plugin_->beep();
        std::cout << "Extension1\n";
    }
private:
    Plugin* plugin_;
};

template <template<typename...> class Plugin>
class Extension2 {
public:
    Extension2() : plugin_(static_cast<Plugin<Extension2>*>(this)) {}
    void beep() {
        plugin_->beep();
        std::cout << "Extension2\n";
    }
private:
    Plugin<Extension2>* plugin_;
};

int main() {
    // This works.
    Extension1<Base1<Extension1>>b;
    b.beep();
    // This doesn't work.
    Extension2<Base1> c;
    c.beep();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: might hurt compilation time. hmm. hopefully this can shorten the error messages.

Comment: This is not how CRTP works. The scheme is `struct Derived : Base<Derived>`. What you try to accomplish looks hopelessly complicated and is no good design.

Comment: @Jodocus: There are multiple Bases. So I try to use a template-template parameter to represent that Base in your example... How to improve the design?

Comment: Before thinking about this, i write them as layers that stack over each other with composition. Composition of layers produce a composition of the methods of the layers, as in crtp. The user can choose how to stack the layers. But the overall object has a method that produces a proxy (a node class) that depends on the composition of the methods. And that gets complicated with all the intermediate passing of types, templates, and methods between the layers... Can't use virtual methods because this has to be fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that the template parameter to `Extension2` does not match the signature that `Base1` has. Another is that `Extension2` does not match the parameter type expected by `Base1`.

If you change the definition of `Extension2` to propertly accept `Base1`, it itself is still not a candidate to be passed to `Base1`. You can workaround that with an inner template class that does match what `Base1` expects. This inner class would look a lot like `Extension1`.

```
template <template<template<typename...> class> class Plugin>
class Extension2 {
    template <class P>
    struct Inner {
        Inner () : plugin_(static_cast<P *>(this)) {}
        void beep() { plugin_->beep(); }
    private:
        P* plugin_;
    };
public:
    Extension2() {}
    void beep() {
        plugin_.beep();
        std::cout << "Extension2\n";
    }
private:
    Inner<Plugin<Inner>> plugin_;
};
```

Comment: One inner class per base class, and a template-template-template parameter. Looks more complicate than composition of layers. Thanks, I will stick with my old code.

Comment: Or I keep that `A<B<A>>` type and use `A().make<B>().make<C>();` to make that.